# How can I automate testing for some javascript API's give a set of Use Cases?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests

I need to build a automated javascript api testing framework which take a combination of Use cases from the given set of use cases and runs the tests and provides the output as pass or fail along with the use case combination.

What should be the basic approach to do so ?

If there is any existing library to do so kindly suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

QUnit would give you a good start: http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit

FireUnit would then give you qunit test output via Firebug: http://ejohn.org/blog/fireunit/

If you're looking to integrate with TeamCity, I wrote a rudiumentary library for qunit: http://qnunit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try [PreemJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preem), it's good for API\Unit javascript testing